# Error when unexpected element (uri:"", local:"response"). Expected elements are <{}quote>

Tags: xml, xsd, jaxb

I'm trying to validate JAXB schema against and XML file and I keep getting the above error. Can you explain to me what <{}Quote> means? and where the error comes from? The Quote is created from the XSD file. Is it because the "quotes" element is not define? Here's my code.

```
package khoa;

import java.io.File;

import javax.xml.XMLConstants;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;
import javax.xml.bind.ValidationEvent;
import javax.xml.bind.ValidationEventHandler;
import javax.xml.validation.Schema;
import javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactory;

import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

import khoa.Quote;
import khoa.Quotes;
public class EmployeeUnmarshaller {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JAXBException, SAXException {
        new EmployeeUnmarshaller().runEmployeeUnmarshaller();
    }

    private void runEmployeeUnmarshaller() throws JAXBException, SAXException {
        JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Quote.class);

        SchemaFactory sf = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI); 
        Schema schema = sf.newSchema(new File("quotes.xsd"));

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();

        unmarshaller.setSchema(schema);
        unmarshaller.setEventHandler(new EmployeeValidationEventHandler());

        System.out.println(unmarshaller.unmarshal(new File("quotes.xml")));

    }
}

class EmployeeValidationEventHandler implements ValidationEventHandler {
    @Override
    public boolean handleEvent(ValidationEvent event) {
         System.out.println("\nEVENT");
            System.out.println("SEVERITY:  " + event.getSeverity());
            System.out.println("MESSAGE:  " + event.getMessage());
            System.out.println("LINKED EXCEPTION:  " + event.getLinkedException());
            System.out.println("LOCATOR");
            System.out.println("    LINE NUMBER:  " + event.getLocator().getLineNumber());
            System.out.println("    COLUMN NUMBER:  " + event.getLocator().getColumnNumber());
            System.out.println("    OFFSET:  " + event.getLocator().getOffset());
            System.out.println("    OBJECT:  " + event.getLocator().getObject());
            System.out.println("    NODE:  " + event.getLocator().getNode());
            System.out.println("    URL:  " + event.getLocator().getURL());
            return true;
    }
}
```

Here's the error I get:

```
EVENT
SEVERITY:  2
MESSAGE:  unexpected element (uri:"", local:"response"). Expected elements are <{}quote>
LINKED EXCEPTION:  null
LOCATOR
    LINE NUMBER:  2
    COLUMN NUMBER:  53
    OFFSET:  -1
    OBJECT:  null
    NODE:  null
    URL:  file:/home/khoa/Documents/work/validation-xsd/quotes.xml
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"response"). Expected elements are <{}quote>
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.handleEvent(UnmarshallingContext.java:726)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportError(Loader.java:247)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportError(Loader.java:242)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportUnexpectedChildElement(Loader.java:109)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext$DefaultRootLoader.childElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:1131)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext._startElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:556)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.startElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:538)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.ValidatingUnmarshaller.startElement(ValidatingUnmarshaller.java:87)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.SAXConnector.startElement(SAXConnector.java:153)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:509)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:374)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl$NSContentDriver.scanRootElementHook(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:613)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:3132)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:852)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:602)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:112)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:505)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:842)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:771)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:643)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:243)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:214)
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:157)
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:162)
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:171)
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:189)
    at khoa.EmployeeUnmarshaller.runEmployeeUnmarshaller(EmployeeUnmarshaller.java:36)
    at khoa.EmployeeUnmarshaller.main(EmployeeUnmarshaller.java:22)
```

Here's the XSD file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">

  <xs:element name="response" type="QuotesResponse"></xs:element>

  <xs:complexType name="QuotesResponse">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="elapsedtime" type="xs:int"></xs:element>
      <xs:element name="quotes">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="quote" type="Quote" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"></xs:element>
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="error" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:string"></xs:attribute>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="Quote">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="adp_100" type="xs:double"></xs:element>
      <xs:element name="adp_200" type="xs:double"></xs:element>
      <xs:element name="adp_50" type="xs:double"></xs:element>
      <xs:element name="adv_21" type="xs:int"></xs:element>
      <xs:element name="adv_30" type="xs:int"></xs:element>
      <xs:element name="adv_90" type="xs:int"></xs:element>
      <xs:element name="ask" type="xs:double"></xs:element>
      <xs:element name="ask_time" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
      <xs:element name="asksz" type="xs:int"></xs:element>
      <xs:element name="basis" type="xs:int"></xs:element>
      <xs:element name="beta" type="xs:double"></xs:element>
      <xs:element name="bid" type="xs:double"></xs:element>
      <xs:element name="bid_time" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
      <xs:element name="bidsz" type="xs:int"></xs:element>
      <xs:element name="bidtick" type="xs:int"></xs:element>
      <xs:element name="chg" type="xs:double"></xs:element>
      <xs:element name="chg_sign" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
      <xs:element name="chg_t" type="xs:double"></xs:element>
      <xs:element name="cl" type="xs:double"></xs:element>
      <xs:element name="cusip" type="xs:int"></xs:element>
      <xs:element name="date" type="xs:date"></xs:element>
      <xs:element name="datetime" type="xs:dateTime"></xs:element>
      <xs:element name="div" type="xs:double"></xs:element>
      <xs:element name="divexdate" type="xs:int"></xs:element>
      <xs:element name="divpaydt" type="xs:int"></xs:element>
      <xs:element name="dollar_value" type="xs:int"></xs:element>
      <xs:element name="eps" type="xs:double"></xs:element>
      <xs:element name="exch" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
      <xs:element name="exch_desc" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
      <xs:element name="hi" type="xs:double"></xs:element>
      <xs:element name="iad" type="xs:int"></xs:element>
      <xs:element name="incr_vl" type="xs:int"></xs:element>
      <xs:element name="last" type="xs:double"></xs:element>
      <xs:element name="lo" type="xs:double"></xs:element>
      <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
      <xs:element name="op_flag" type="xs:int"></xs:element>
      <xs:element name="opn" type="xs:double"></xs:element>
      <xs:element name="pchg" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
      <xs:element name="pchg_sign" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
      <xs:element name="pcls" type="xs:double"></xs:element>
      <xs:element name="pe" type="xs:double"></xs:element>
      <xs:element name="phi" type="xs:double"></xs:element>
      <xs:element name="plo" type="xs:double"></xs:element>
      <xs:element name="popn" type="xs:double"></xs:element>
      <xs:element name="pr_adp_100" type="xs:double"></xs:element>
      <xs:element name="pr_adp_200" type="xs:double"></xs:element>
      <xs:element name="pr_adp_50" type="xs:double"></xs:element>
      <xs:element name="pr_date" type="xs:date"></xs:element>
      <xs:element name="prbook" type="xs:double"></xs:element>
      <xs:element name="prchg" type="xs:double"></xs:element>
      <xs:element name="pvol" type="xs:int"></xs:element>
      <xs:element name="secclass" type="xs:int"></xs:element>
      <xs:element name="sesn" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
      <xs:element name="sho" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
      <xs:element name="symbol" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
      <xs:element name="tcond" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
      <xs:element name="timestamp" type="xs:int"></xs:element>
      <xs:element name="tr_num" type="xs:int"></xs:element>
      <xs:element name="tradetick" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
      <xs:element name="trend" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
      <xs:element name="vl" type="xs:int"></xs:element>
      <xs:element name="volatility12" type="xs:double"></xs:element>
      <xs:element name="vwap" type="xs:double"></xs:element>
      <xs:element name="wk52hi" type="xs:double"></xs:element>
      <xs:element name="wk52hidate" type="xs:int"></xs:element>
      <xs:element name="wk52lo" type="xs:double"></xs:element>
      <xs:element name="wk52lodate" type="xs:int"></xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```

Here's the XML content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response id="2a67cd61-7244-45f8-b39f-0bc0f5694362">
<elapsedtime>0</elapsedtime>
<quotes>
  <quotetype>Delayed - market data delayed by at least 15 minutes</quotetype>
  <quote>
    <adp_100>31.7769</adp_100>
    <adp_200>27.8477</adp_200>
    <adp_50>31.3177</adp_50>
    <adv_21>15638419</adv_21>
    <adv_30>19404542</adv_30>
    <adv_90>26872030</adv_90>
    <ask>0.000</ask>
    <ask_time>00:00</ask_time>
    <asksz>0</asksz>
    <basis>na</basis>
    <beta>0.8023</beta>
    <bid>0.000</bid>
    <bid_time>00:00</bid_time>
    <bidsz>0</bidsz>
    <bidtick>d</bidtick>
    <chg>0</chg>
    <chg_sign>e</chg_sign>
    <chg_t>na</chg_t>
    <cl>33.520</cl>
    <contract_size>na</contract_size>
    <cusip>na</cusip>
    <date>2018-05-25</date>
    <datetime>2018-05-25T00:00:00-04:00</datetime>
    <days_to_expiration>na</days_to_expiration>
    <div>na</div>
    <divexdate>na</divexdate>
    <divfreq>Q</divfreq>
    <divpaydt>na</divpaydt>
    <dollar_value>350661442.245</dollar_value>
    <eps>0.01</eps>
    <exch>NYSE</exch>
    <exch_desc>New York Stock Exchange</exch_desc>
    <hi>33.990</hi>
    <iad>na</iad>
    <idelta>na</idelta>
    <igamma>na</igamma>
    <imp_volatility>na</imp_volatility>
    <incr_vl>0</incr_vl>
    <irho>na</irho>
    <issue_desc>na</issue_desc>
    <itheta>na</itheta>
    <ivega>na</ivega>
    <last>33.630</last>
    <lo>33.310</lo>
    <name>TWITTER INC</name>
    <op_delivery>na</op_delivery>
    <op_flag>1</op_flag>
    <op_style>na</op_style>
    <op_subclass>na</op_subclass>
    <openinterest>na</openinterest>
    <opn>33.540</opn>
    <opt_val>na</opt_val>
    <pchg>0.00</pchg>
    <pchg_sign>na</pchg_sign>
    <pcls>33.630</pcls>
    <pe>3363</pe>
    <phi>33.755</phi>
    <plo>33.120</plo>
    <popn>33.440</popn>
    <pr_adp_100>31.8031</pr_adp_100>
    <pr_adp_200>27.7884</pr_adp_200>
    <pr_adp_50>31.2283</pr_adp_50>
    <pr_date>2018-05-24</pr_date>
    <pr_openinterest>na</pr_openinterest>
    <prbook>5.019</prbook>
    <prchg>0.080</prchg>
    <prem_mult>na</prem_mult>
    <put_call>na</put_call>
    <pvol>0</pvol>
    <qcond>38</qcond>
    <rootsymbol>na</rootsymbol>
    <secclass>0</secclass>
    <sesn>na</sesn>
    <sho>752667000</sho>
    <strikeprice>na</strikeprice>
    <symbol>TWTR</symbol>
    <tcond>29</tcond>
    <timestamp>1527488058</timestamp>
    <tr_num>41737</tr_num>
    <tradetick>e</tradetick>
    <trend>na</trend>
    <under_cusip>na</under_cusip>
    <undersymbol>na</undersymbol>
    <vl>10424410</vl>
    <volatility12>0.4884</volatility12>
    <vwap>33.638</vwap>
    <wk52hi>36.80</wk52hi>
    <wk52hidate>20180314</wk52hidate>
    <wk52lo>15.67</wk52lo>
    <wk52lodate>20170811</wk52lodate>
    <xdate>na</xdate>
    <xday>na</xday>
    <xmonth>na</xmonth>
    <xyear>na</xyear>
    <yield>na</yield>
  </quote>
  <quote>
    <adp_100>11.0581</adp_100>
    <adp_200>11.5676</adp_200>
    <adp_50>11.2900</adp_50>
    <adv_21>26975556</adv_21>
    <adv_30>32302687</adv_30>
    <adv_90>40297310</adv_90>
    <ask>0.000</ask>
    <ask_time>00:00</ask_time>
    <asksz>0</asksz>
    <basis>na</basis>
    <beta>0.8333</beta>
    <bid>0.000</bid>
    <bid_time>00:00</bid_time>
    <bidsz>0</bidsz>
    <bidtick>d</bidtick>
    <chg>0</chg>
    <chg_sign>e</chg_sign>
    <chg_t>na</chg_t>
    <cl>11.620</cl>
    <contract_size>na</contract_size>
    <cusip>na</cusip>
    <date>2018-05-25</date>
    <datetime>2018-05-25T00:00:00-04:00</datetime>
    <days_to_expiration>na</days_to_expiration>
    <div>0.15</div>
    <divexdate>20180419</divexdate>
    <divfreq>Q</divfreq>
    <divpaydt>20180601</divpaydt>
    <dollar_value>222009310.770</dollar_value>
    <eps>19.3</eps>
    <exch>NYSE</exch>
    <exch_desc>New York Stock Exchange</exch_desc>
    <hi>11.605</hi>
    <iad>0.6</iad>
    <idelta>na</idelta>
    <igamma>na</igamma>
    <imp_volatility>na</imp_volatility>
    <incr_vl>0</incr_vl>
    <irho>na</irho>
    <issue_desc>na</issue_desc>
    <itheta>na</itheta>
    <ivega>na</ivega>
    <last>11.510</last>
    <lo>11.470</lo>
    <name>FORD MOTOR CO. (DE)</name>
    <op_delivery>na</op_delivery>
    <op_flag>1</op_flag>
    <op_style>na</op_style>
    <op_subclass>na</op_subclass>
    <openinterest>na</openinterest>
    <opn>11.560</opn>
    <opt_val>na</opt_val>
    <pchg>0.00</pchg>
    <pchg_sign>na</pchg_sign>
    <pcls>11.510</pcls>
    <pe>5.9637</pe>
    <phi>11.650</phi>
    <plo>11.440</plo>
    <popn>11.450</popn>
    <pr_adp_100>11.0538</pr_adp_100>
    <pr_adp_200>11.5719</pr_adp_200>
    <pr_adp_50>11.2869</pr_adp_50>
    <pr_date>2018-05-24</pr_date>
    <pr_openinterest>na</pr_openinterest>
    <prbook>1.291</prbook>
    <prchg>0.170</prchg>
    <prem_mult>na</prem_mult>
    <put_call>na</put_call>
    <pvol>0</pvol>
    <qcond>38</qcond>
    <rootsymbol>na</rootsymbol>
    <secclass>0</secclass>
    <sesn>na</sesn>
    <sho>3914102000</sho>
    <strikeprice>na</strikeprice>
    <symbol>F</symbol>
    <tcond>29</tcond>
    <timestamp>1527488058</timestamp>
    <tr_num>39010</tr_num>
    <tradetick>e</tradetick>
    <trend>na</trend>
    <under_cusip>na</under_cusip>
    <undersymbol>na</undersymbol>
    <vl>19337470</vl>
    <volatility12>0.2115</volatility12>
    <vwap>11.480</vwap>
    <wk52hi>13.48</wk52hi>
    <wk52hidate>20180116</wk52hidate>
    <wk52lo>10.14</wk52lo>
    <wk52lodate>20180302</wk52lodate>
    <xdate>na</xdate>
    <xday>na</xday>
    <xmonth>na</xmonth>
    <xyear>na</xyear>
    <yield>5.2129</yield>
  </quote>
</quotes><error>Success</error></response>
```

Comment: The notation <{}Quote> is a concise way of saying "An element with local name 'Quote' in no namespace".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You JAXB context is created only with the `Quote` class:

```
JAXBContext.newInstance(Quote.class);
```

So JAXB does not know about the `Response` class which configures the top-level `response` element.

One of the options is to add `Response` to the enumeration of classes you create `JAXBContext` for:

```
JAXBContext.newInstance(Response.class, Quote.class)
```

Alternatively, create `JAXBContext` for the whole package:

```
JAXBContext.newInstance(Quote.class.getPackage().getName())
```

I prefer the second option.

Comment: Thank you. The first method didn't work but the second one works. Now this code shows me exactly where the problems are.